# Asked on Windows Azure deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, azure

I'm developing an application that I want to deploy to Windows Azure. Before doing so, I try to calculate the price of this deployment and I have not very clear. The deployment consists of one side of an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with a SQL DB which will have a high number of reads (for that use asynchronous methods) and return the results to a web client in json format.

Furthermore, for users who do searches, I'll have a chat server in Node.js in which users can communicate application.

I know that in terms of outbound traffic and storage in my DB depends entirely on the number of users, but what kind of service I choose Windows Azure application to ASP.NET and server chat? Websites?? Cloud services?? In how web roles and worker roles results? What if I want scalability of any of the two services? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an asp.net mvc application *directly* to Azure Websites; in order to use a web role you need to have additional project setup. Also, websites allows you do deploy directly from source control. Since they are free to try, start with a website and see where it takes you. If it works, keep using it, if it limits you, try switching to a web role.